# For loop interpretation

Tags: java

I have two array lists;

```
        ArrayList<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<>();

        bankAccounts.add(new CheckingAccount    ("chk001",  500.00)) ;
        bankAccounts.add(new SavingsAccount     ("sav001", 5000.00)) ;
        bankAccounts.add(new LineOfCreditAccount("loc001",36000.00)) ;
        bankAccounts.add(new CheckingAccount    ("chk002",  299.00)) ;
        bankAccounts.add(new SavingsAccount     ("sav002", 9049.00)) ;
        bankAccounts.add(new LineOfCreditAccount("loc002",10000.00)) ;


        ArrayList<Transaction> transactionList = new ArrayList<>() ;


        transactionList.add(new DepositTransaction   ("chk001",  500.00)) ;
        transactionList.add(new DepositTransaction   ("sav001", 5000.00)) ;
        transactionList.add(new DepositTransaction   ("loc001",  350.00)) ;
```

and transactionList has a method called `applyTransaction()`

As now, I am accessing each element from `bankAccounts and transactionList`as shown below

```
BankAccount test = bankAccounts.get(0)
           ,test1 = bankAccounts.get(1);
Transaction t0 = transactionList.get(0)
           ,t1 = transactionList.get(1)
           ,t3 = transactionList.get(3);
```

And applying each transaction to the appropriate bank accounts as shown below

```
t0.applyTransaction(test);
t3.applyTransaction(test);
t1.applyTransaction(test1);
```

How can I put all this in one for loop and accessing items from each list not manually like `test1 = bankAccounts.get(1)`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: here is your for loop tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: I have tried all that and cannot seem to get this work.

Comment: Then show some more code and exception or syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a code in your `BankAccount` constructor (the field that stores "chk001", "sav001" and so on). Now, you have to differenciate to which `BankAccount` you want to apply your transaction to.

So first lets iterate through all the `Transactions` and get the code of each of these `Transaction` which is the code of the `BankAccount` that needs to be applied and retrieve the actual account so we can apply it on the `Transaction` like this:

```
for(Transaction transaction : transactionList) 
{
    //get the type of account chk001, sav001, loc001 ..
    String accountType = transaction.getBankAccountType();
    BankAccount account = getTypeAccount(accountType)

    if(account != null)
    {
        transaction.applyTransaction(account);  
    } 

}
```

The previous code assumes you have on each `Transaction` object a getter to retrieve its code. If you don't have it you could go to the `Transaction` class and add it yourself.

Then you could create a helper method in the same class where you are creating the loop logic that retrieves the actual `BankAccount` that matches the the code on the transaction like this:

```
private BankAccount getTypeAccount(String accountType)
{
     for(BankAccount account : bankAccounts)
     {
           if(account.getCode().equals(accountType))
           {
                return account;
           }
     }
     return null;
}
```

And finally as seen on the first snippet you apply the transaction sending the correct `BankAccount` by doing: `transaction.applyTransaction(account);`

A little tutorial about for loops including For-Each
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, but I tried your code and every transaction get applied to every bank account rather than appropriate ones. I am just out of solutions.

Comment: what is the order you want to apply bankAccount's into transaction?

Comment: I have bank accounts "chk" for checking, "sav" for saving, "loc" for line of credit. I am actually editing my post to add more info..

Comment: @Infinite_Loop check my updated answer. That should give you a better picture, cheers

Answer (score 1):

you can loop your Transaction ArrayList and then access the elements of every ArrayList as shown in the next example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < transactionList.size(); i++){
    transactionList.get(i).applyTransaction(bankAccounts.get(i));
}
```

Hope it's useful to you!, any doubt let me know.

Comment: Hey @Fabian Rivera, thank you so much for your suggestion. I tried your code and get this error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4 and then I tried something else which is this code: 'for(int i = 0; i < transactionList.size(); i++){
 for(int j = 0; j < bankAccounts.size(); j++)
  transactionList.get(i).applyTransaction(bankAccounts.get(j));
}
' Now, each transaction gets applied to all types of accounts, not the appropriate accounts.

Comment: This assumes the length of both arrays are the same, but it is actually not. there are only two bank accounts and the loop tries to reach a 3rd non existing account

Comment: Yeah, my answer assumes that the length of the arrays is the same, that is how I understood the problem. @Bartzilla's solution seems good, try with it!